# GraphQLHttpException Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: InternalServerError

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

We are on Sitecore 10.1 (IaaS) and have used Sitecore Serialization and CLI to install items on higher environments as a task in our Release pipeline. So far it has worked fine for us. But during our last release, we got below exception while trying to install Sitecore items -

```
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2383724Z [GraphQLHttpException] Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: InternalServerError
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2499102Z at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.ReadHttpResponseMessageAsync(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2500367Z at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.PostAsync(GraphQLRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2501478Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Core.Client.GraphQl.SitecoreApiClient.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<RunQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2502543Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2504096Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.MakeAuthenticatedRequestInternal(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\OidcAuthenticationProvider.cs:line 87
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2505209Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.MakeAuthenticatedRequest(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\OidcAuthenticationProvider.cs:line 76
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2506308Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider.MakeAuthenticatedRequest(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider.cs:line 106
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2507416Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Models.EnvironmentConfiguration.MakeAuthenticatedRequest(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Models\EnvironmentConfiguration.cs:line 275
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2508581Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Core.Client.GraphQl.SitecoreApiClient.RunQuery(String servicePath, GraphQLRequest request, Boolean assertNoErrors, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2509746Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.ExecuteSingleBatchQuery[T](String batchQueryFragment, TreeScope scope, ItemSpec[] specs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2510916Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.CreateParallelBatchQuery[T](String batchQueryFragment, TreeScope scope, ItemSpec[] specs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2512035Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.GetTreeNodesInternal(IEnumerable`1 itemSpecs, TreeScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2513104Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.GetTreeNodes(IEnumerable`1 itemSpecs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-20T21:17:46.2514024Z at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeCongruencyCommandBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<CreateProcessDataflow>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2023-12-20T21:17:46.3912755Z ##[error]Sitecore CLI is failed
```

What surprised us is that we did not encounter this error in release to lower environments with exact same items, same build and same server setup. We looked into Sitecore CM logs and we could only found below error -

```
11808 21:17:36 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: The request queue limit of the session is exceeded.
Source: System.Web
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.QueueRef()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSession()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This error did not exist before in our CM logs. We found [this ticket](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35742/sitecore-serialization-error-http-error-invoking-graphql-endpoint-https-cm-h) which talks about similar exception and based on the recommendation in this ticket, we tried to increase the polling interval to 60 but it did not help.

We recently increased cache sizes for AccessResultCache etc.only in our PROD environment. Is it possible remotely that this could have ate up some cache which is used by GraphQL for managing these request queues.

Has anyone encountered this issue or any suggestions that can help us move forward are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check the "aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession" value in your web.config?
increasing it may help to solve this issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7.x

Comment: If you just deploy the templates/rendering, ... and not the actual content, I suggest thinking about using the Item as Resource(IAR) deployment:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/using-items-as-resources.html