# XMCLOUD Serialization Error [GraphQLHttpException] Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code 524

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud, serialization, sitecore-cli

We are currently experiencing a challenge while running a CLI command.

The issue happening during the serialization process command

> dotnet sitecore ser push -n 'Prod'

The exception message we are getting is this

> Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code:524

To get more detailed logs: Tried this command

> dotnet sitecore ser push -n "Prod" --include Data.abcCanada --verbose -t --what-if

```
dotnet sitecore ser push -n "Prod" --include Data.abcCanada --verbose -t --what-if
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@5.2.113
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@5.2.113
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Indexing@5.2.113
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.ResourcePackage@5.2.113
Looking for package Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.XMCloud@1.1.30
Finished resolving plugins. Total elapsed resolution time: 138ms
What if mode is active. No changes will be made.
> Resolving modules from expressions: 
  * src/*.module.json
  * src/Project/abcCanada/*.module.json
>> Resolved 7 local module(s) using glob(s) 
  * src/*.module.json
  * src/Project/abcCanada/*.module.json
Matched module configurations: Data.abcCanada
[master] Source: serialized items (1 subtrees)
[master] Destination: Sitecore endpoint prod (Host: https://xmc-abccanada1-abc-prod.sitecorecloud.io/, DB: master)
[master] Loading data...
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] Sending GraphQL request 1
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] [Version comparison] versionComparisonEnabled: True
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] [Version comparison] Added sitecore-graphql-version-comparing-enabled: True
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] [Version comparison] Added sitecore-graphql-cli-version: 5.2.113
[master] FSIndex: Loaded filesystem indices in 405ms (0 metadatas)
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] **HTTP Error invoking GraphQL endpoint https://xmc-abccanada1-abc-prod.sitecorecloud.io//sitecore/api/management**
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] Query 1: 
query($aP: String! $aD: String! $aE: [String] $aS: TreeScope!) {
a:
  serialize(path: $aP, database: $aD, scope: $aS , excludedFieldIds : $aE) {
    id
    parentId
    templateId
    path
    hasChildren
    dataSignature
  }
}

[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] Query 1 variables: {
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)]   "aP": "/sitecore/content/abc/abcCanada/Data",
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)]   "aD": "master",
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)]   "aE": [],
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)]   "aS": "ITEM_AND_DESCENDANTS"      
[master] [GraphQL> Get metadata (master; 1 specs, ItemAndDescendants)] }
[GraphQLHttpException] **Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: 524**
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.ReadHttpResponseMessageAsync(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.PostAsync(GraphQLRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Core.Client.GraphQl.SitecoreApiClient.c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.MakeAuthenticatedRequestInternal(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\OidcAuthenticationProvider.cs:line 86
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.MakeAuthenticatedRequest(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Authentication\OidcAuthenticationProvider.cs:line 30
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Models.EnvironmentConfiguration.MakeAuthenticatedRequest(HttpClient client, Func`2 requestAction) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\Models\EnvironmentConfiguration.cs:line 313
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Core.Client.GraphQl.SitecoreApiClient.RunQuery(String servicePath, GraphQLRequest request, Boolean assertNoErrors, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.ExecuteSingleBatchQuery[T](String batchQueryFragment, TreeScope scope, ItemSpec[] specs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.c__DisplayClass21_0`1.b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

**We also referred this post:**

[Sitecore serialization error : HTTP Error invoking GraphQL endpoint https://CM hostname/sitecore/api/management](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35742/sitecore-serialization-error-http-error-invoking-graphql-endpoint-https-cm-h)
[GraphQLHttpException Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: InternalServerError](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36726/graphqlhttpexception-unexpected-httpresponsemessage-with-code-internalservererr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**These are options for 10.x Sitecore. We would greatly appreciate any help in resolving it in XMCloud.**

Comment: i have answered https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36726/graphqlhttpexception-unexpected-httpresponsemessage-with-code-internalservererr

Can you please add some more information:
- How much data do you want to push (if you know)?
- Is the issue reproducible in other environments?
- Do you see any error on the target CM server logs (in your case prod)?